# xCode: Force orientation for iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, swift4

I have application for iPhone's and iPad. However, for iPad I have to force it for landscape only and for iPhone I have no restrictions.

As I understand such solution can not be done via device orientation property in project properties, which I have to choice all for iPhone, and have to be via code.

I am a new one in Swift and will glad to get some explanations.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
    if(UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad){

        let value = UIInterfaceOrientation.LandscapeRight.rawValue
        UIDevice.currentDevice().setValue(value, forKey: "orientation")


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found those options in Info.plist
Works great!
[image]